# Listing all permissions for dynamo in a policy won't work but wildcard does dynamodb:*

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

So I'm trying to figure out the minimum permissions an EMR cluster would need to create a hive table, from a step. I found it needs something from dynamodb because it won't work unless there's a "dynamodb:*" in the policy (it does have consistent view set on the cluster). I want to know the specific permissions it needs rather than wildcarding all of them. A brute force way of doing this is that I am using a policy that lists all the dynamodb actions and then I'm deleting them one by one and making the table again in a step on the cluster to see if it fails or not. But when I use the wild card it works, but listing them all doesn't.

When I use:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
...(other stuff)
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It can create the table just fine. But when I list each resource (from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html) it fails to create a table.
Which would look like this:

```
...
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
            ...
```

The table is just an example table with crime data that looks like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE crimes (
id string,
...
case_location string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
LOCATION 's3://<path>/crimes/data';
```

There shouldn't be a difference between the wildcard and listing all the services, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a memory problem.

We don't know exactly what happened but the cluster was an EMR cluster with m1.medium's since we were just testing. Well, I didn't think to click on the error log outputs since I was changing the permissions so I assumed a permission error (and previous failures were permission errors) but after looking at the error logs, they were saying 'out of memory'.

So I don't know exactly what was happening but sounds like we were so close to using all of the memory that listing all the permissions vs using a wild card used up what was left of the memory. Just one of those out there errors you never expect = )

Comment: If anyone is curious, I was able now to get that for a step in EMR to make a hive table, it needed this:


    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

That should work - as in I don't know of any difference but then why bother listing services if you are not going to restrict anything.

I highly recommend using the policy simulator to test IAM profiles and API calls - see https://policysim.aws.amazon.com.

I would also recommend splitting up the S3 profile from the DynamoDB profile and use multiple statements.

It could be a missing service or resource not specified properly. The error messages and error codes from actual API calls are not always helpful from an IAM perspective which is why I recommend using the policysim tool.

Here's an example of something that works for me for DynamoDB and restricting specific resources.

```
        {
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:GetRecords",
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:CreateTable",
            "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/Foo",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/Bar"
        ]
    }
```